# Query that ranks students order by marks and give the position of student even when there are students with equal marks

Tags: mysql

I need an sql that will rank students order by marks scored in a specific examtyp e.g CAT1 and give exact position even if the students have equal marks e.g in this sample data admNo 2525 and admNo 4093 scored equal marks in CAT1, so i need an sql that will fetch the positions as the same and skip give the next student number 3. the following sql that i tried does not consider a scenario like this.

```
$sql = "SELECT q1.rownum
FROM 
    (
        SELECT *, @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS rownum
        FROM $table t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
        WHERE examtyp =? AND termId=? AND year=? 
        ORDER BY points DESC
    ) q1
WHERE q1.admNo=$admNo"; 

resid  admNo streamIdexamtyptermIdmarks gradepointyear
1       2129    0   CAT1    1   525     C   62  2013
2       4093    0   CAT1    1   569     B+  69  2013
3       2129    0   CAT2    1   550     B+  67  2013
4       4093    0   CAT2    1   556     B+  68  2013
6       2129    0   FINAL   1   559     B+  68  2013
7       2129    0   AVERAGE 1   545     B   66  2013
7       4093    0   FINAL   1   581     B+  70  2013
8       4093    0   AVERAGE 1   569     B+  69  2013
9       2525    9   CAT1    1   569     B+  69  2013
```

Comment: Where does aggregate_points come from? That SQL does not seem to match the outpit. Please add source table and data and desired output so we don't have to guess

Comment: Yes, as @gbn points out, the column names in the table do not match the names in the query (examCategory - examtyp,  aggregate_points - points).

Comment: I've answered a [related MySQL question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/40417/2660) about ranking rows by some kind of score. My answer uses techniques described [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8913662/877069). If you provide sample data and expected output, we can better help you.

Comment: Another similar question: [Sorting the Table and getting the position](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18316/sorting-the-table-and-getting-the-position/18326#18326)

Comment: And here's a neat (but more inefficient) way to do it with `GROUP_CONCAT`: [Another ranking trick](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com.au/2009/09/mysql-another-ranking-trick.html)

Comment: oh am sorry it should be points not aggregate_points

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t1.id, mark,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM marktable t2 WHERE t2.mark > t1.mark) +1
AS rnk
FROM marktable t1 order by rnk;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/154b0/7)